# avoid page numbers in minitoc if tocloft is loaded

Tags: page-numbering, tocloft, minitoc

Below is a MWE which shows page numbers in the minitoc as soon as I uncomment the line loading the `tocloft` package. How to prevent this in addition to setting `\mtcsetpagenumbers{minitoc}{off}`?

```
\documentclass{book}

%\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
%\makeatletter
%\def\l@subsubsection#1#2{{\let\numberline\@gobble{\sffamily\small #1~[#2]}}}
%\makeatother

\usepackage{minitoc} % Mini-ToCs with loose line spacing
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{2}
\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{} % for empty title
\mtcsetpagenumbers{minitoc}{off} % turn off page numbering in minitocs

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}
  \dominitoc
  \tableofcontents
  {\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Chapter title}}
  \minitoc
  \section{Section}
  \subsection{Subsection}
  \subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Additionally, if I uncomment the context around `\def\l@subsubsection#1#2` (to achieve a compact TOC similar to that one in the `microtype` manual; line was copied from there) the minitoc shows the subsubsection even if `minitocdepth=2`.

Comment: I've fixed the description. I meant tocloft. But anyway, I don't understand how your suggestion should help. I need both the tocloft and minitoc package but as soon as tocloft is loaded it disables some functionality of minitoc (hiding page numbers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that minitoc defers when tocloft is loaded first, and tocloft changes `\l@section` etc. when loaded after.

BTW, `\l@subsection` is supposed to check `\value{tocdepth}` and your (commented out) replacement didn't.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{minitoc} % Mini-ToCs with loose line spacing
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{2}
\mtcsettitle{minitoc}{} % for empty title
\mtcsetpagenumbers{minitoc}{off} % turn off page numbering in minitocs

\makeatletter
\let\normal@section=\l@section
\let\normal@subsection=\l@subsection
\makeatother

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\let\l@section=\normal@section
\let\l@subsection=\normal@subsection
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}


  \dominitoc
  \tableofcontents
  {\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Chapter title}}
  \minitoc
  \section{Section}
  \subsection{Subsection}
  \subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, great. I also changed `\l@subsubsection` to `\def\l@subsubsection#1#2{{\ifnum\c@tocdepth>2 \let\numberline\@gobble{\sffamily\small #1~[#2]} \fi}}`. Is there any way to ensure a line break, if the subsubsection is the last entry in the toc? With my definition, no line break is introduced and the first chapter title is printed right after `Subsubsection [1]` without a new line in between.

Comment: Just put a \par inside the \fi.  That is what \@dottedtocline does.

Comment: With `\par` it works like expected. Unfortunately, I found a big drawback of your solution above. Any font change of TOC-entries, i. e. with `\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}` does not work anymore, because it gets reseted in the line `\let\l@section=\normal@section`. If I place the renew command after this line, it does not work either. How to solve this?

Comment: The whole point was to prevent tocloft from changing the \l@subsection.  Personally, I avoid tocloft and just change \l@secttion etc. directly.  You can use the etoolkit to replace \normalfont in \l@subsection, etc.  Or try \meaning\l@subsection to see what minitoc has one.